# Blend / XAML: How to modify the center of a path, that's an item of a pathlistbox

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, center

SO I have a pathlistbox, the path to follow, that holds an item that is itself a path, the item.
The item on the pathlistbox correctly stands on a point of the path.

BUT, the item is centered on that point (as it should be) and I would like to somehow change that center to be at the bottom of the item/path.

Example: the pathlistbox would be a straight line like a road, and the item a person, drawn as a path.
Right now, the person would appear too low, ie with her feet below the road. And I would like the feet to be ON the road. Trying to drag the path's center point has no impact.

If anyone can help, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: You would have to post (the relevant parts of) your XAML. At least the control or data template of your list item.

Comment: Ya like Clemens said some xaml would help, but I think what you're going to be ultimately looking for is adjusting your RenderTransformOrigin of that object.